# How to merge two data frames using condition in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables

The first table is :

| key | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 05/04/2019 | 23/01/2020 |
| 15 | 23/10/2017 | 23/06/2018 |
| 03 | 11/05/2020 | 23/07/2022 |
| 11 | 17/11/2016 | 23/10/2018 |

The second table is :

| key | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 01/10/2017 | 230 |
| 23 | 14/11/2019 | 100 |
| 03 | 10/01/2010 | 400 |
| 15 | 30/05/2018 | 830 |

How to merge these two tables using Pandas so that it merges by matching the key field and checking if the date of the second table falls within the start and end date of first table

So the merged output should be:

| key | start | end | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 05/04/2019 | 23/01/2020 | 14/11/2019 | 100 |
| 15 | 23/10/2017 | 23/06/2018 | 30/05/2018 | 830 |
| 03 | 11/05/2020 | 23/07/2022 |  |  |
| 11 | 17/11/2016 | 23/10/2018 | 01/10/2017 | 230 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key')
df_merge = df_merge.query('date >= start and date <= end')

df_out = df1.merge(df_merge, on=['start','end'], how='left').fillna('')
print(df_out)
```